# check common values in 2 arrays and put the different in third array

Tags: c, arrays

i have this code ... for a function who get 7 numbers from the user and put it into array number 1.... and second create a random numbers and put them into array number 2....check if there is a common values ...(not only in the same place for example: not only if ar1[1]==ar2[1] ... but to check for all places if there is a common values)....and to put the different values in third array...to create third array and put the not common values in it ... this is my code:

```
 //includes
# include  <stdio.h>
# include  <conio.h>
# include  <stdlib.h>
# include  <time.h>

//define
#define N 7
//prototype
void randomArray(int maxVal,int ar2[]);

int main()
{
//variables/arrays
int ar1[N],ar2[N],ar3[N],i,z,t,temp,maxVal,counter;

printf("Please Enter %d numbers: ",N);
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&ar1[i]);
}

while(1)
{
printf("Please enter a max value: ");
scanf("%d",&maxVal);

if(maxVal>0)
    break;
}
randomArray(maxVal,ar2);


getch();
return 0;
}

//randomArray
void randomArray(int maxVal,int ar2[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
     /* get random value between minVal and maxVal */
        ar2[i] = (rand() % (maxVal+1 - 1)) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: what’s your question again?

Comment: Why is there C# in your title?

Comment: my code above return 2 arrays ,in the first array the user enters 7 numbers ... then there are a random array...and send 7 random values to array 2 ....now i need to check if there is a common values in the two arrays above...and to creat a third array and to send the non-common values to third array...and print the third array values...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple, brute force approach. It first compares each element in array 1 against every element in array 2 and stores it if it's not in array 2. Then it does the same thing for array 2. Then it prints array 3.

Note: you need to change the size of array 3 to N*2 in case there are no matches. Also, set all elements in array 3 to 0 first to mark as a non-result. Or keep track of array 3's length.

```
int ar3[N*2] = {0};
int index = 0;
//Check 1st array
printf("Array 1:\t");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    bool in_array = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        if (ar1[i] == ar2[k]) {
            in_array = true;
                    break;
        }
    }
    if (!in_array) {
        ar3[index++] = ar1[i];
    }
    printf(" %d", ar1[i]);
}
//Check 2nd array
printf("\r\nArray 2:\t");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    bool in_array = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        if (ar2[i] == ar1[k]) {
            in_array = true;
                    break;
        }
    }
    if (!in_array) {
        ar3[index++] = ar2[i];
    }
    printf(" %d", ar2[i]);
}

// Print result
printf("\r\nUnique:\t");
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N*2; i++) {
    if (0 == ar3[i]) {
        break;
    }
    printf(" %d", ar3[i]);
}
```

If this works for you, please accept as correct answer.

Comment: didnt work... i need if the arr1:1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and arr2:4,5,6,7,8,9,1 ... to put the non-common:3,8,9 in a third array and to printf this third array